# How Cassandra uses memory

Tags: cassandra

What data does Cassandra stores in memory? Indexes, metadata, keys?

Because for Couchbase, even though data are persisted to disk, all metadata and keys are still in memory. This poses a problem because memory usage will keep increasing and no further inserts are possible once memory is maxed out.

Is Cassandra similar in this sense?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra stores key/value pairs of all configured column-familys in memory data structures called Memtables. And later it flushes the in-memory data to the disk during comapction or when the threshold (~64mb configurable) is reached. Take a look at this cassandra wiki:http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableThresholds

Comment: Dont forget the key (on by default but can be disabled) and column caches. Also this [memtables](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable) link will be a good intro to what a Memtable is and when it gets flushed to disk to free up heap space.

Comment: Hi, so if I understand correctly, once Cassandra flushes there will be nothing in the memory? No keys or metadata in the memory kept for faster future search?

Comment: @Daniel pointed out Bloomfilters per sstable, Row & Column caches, partition summary is all in memory. See the following link about Cassandra Reads:[link](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/dml/dml_about_reads_c.html)

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra does needs only three things to store permanently in memory:  (1) Bloomfilters (very sparse), (2) row & (3) column cache (any iff exists).
Additionally Cassandra needs memory for the biggest table -- I suppose the biggest ResultSet should be enough. So Cassandra may be okay with rather descent memory.